# Column keys to fetch for select_avg active record result in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have this active record query.

```
$this->db->select_avg('score');
$this->db->select_min('time');
$q = $this->db->get_where('place_rvw', array('place_id' => $place_id));
```

I want to know what array keys I will use to access the results if I use result_array() since the select statement uses functions. Will the code below work?

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row)
{
    $score_mean = $row['AVG(score)'];
    $day_one = $row['MIN(time)'];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not run it at see for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what they keys are you could always use PHP to print them for you.

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {
 print_r(array_keys($row));
}
```